# Infinite loop on onSnapshop() firebase subscription using redux toolkit

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux-toolkit

I try to add my Redux store when anything changes in Firestore, but run in n infinite loop.
I already read the solutions for similar problems, but in my case I need a permanent subscription to firestore cause I need every change from Firestore.

I simply listen to changes like this:

```
const q = query(collection(db, "test"));
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
    if (change.type === "added") {
      // dispatch(action);
    }
    if (change.type === "modified") {

    }
    if (change.type === "removed") {
      data.splice(data.findIndex((e) => e.id === change.doc.id));
    }
    console.log(redux state)
  });
})
```

my console.log runs in an infinite loop, maybe cause the snapshop is always updating.

is there maybe a way to use useEffect to prevent the loop ?

(The Configuration etc. works fine, thats why I didn´t copy it)

Comment: This seems invalid `console.log(redux state)` and `data` seems uninitialized, but aside from that I don't see any problem with the code you shared. How does the infinite loop come about?

Comment: In case of (change.type === "added") runs a endless loop and the dispatch function spams into the redux store, it works fine with a local useState, the loop occurs only if I try to push it in Redux